# Why is the star quantifier greedier than the plus quantifier in Java regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have text I'm trying to extract from `LogicalID` and `SupplyChain` from

```
 <LogicalID>SupplyChain</Logical>
```

At first I used the following regex:

```
.*([A-Za-z]+)>([A-Za-z]+)<.*
```

This matched as follows:

```
["D", "SupplyChain"]
```

In a fit of desperation, I tried using the asterisk instead of the plus:

```
.*([A-Za-z]*)>([A-Za-z]+)<.*
```

This matched perfectly.

The documentation says `*` matches zero or more times and `+` matches one or more times. Why is `*` greedier than `+`?

EDIT: It's been pointed out to me that this isn't the case below. The order of operations explains why the first match group is actually null.

Comment: What do you mean by greedier? Have you tried changing places `.*` with `.+`? It seems that it is not greediness, but order of placing them that matters here.

Comment: It seemed like greediness, and it's actually order of execution. I've gathered this in the answer below from @Airos.

Comment: Putting `?` after `*` in your first regex will also make this match work, i.e. `.*?([A-Za-z]+)>([A-Za-z]+)<.*` .  I'm pointing that out just because it might help you see how things work, but @anubhava's answer is probably a better one, depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a difference in greediness. In your first regex:

```
.*([A-Za-z]+)>([A-Za-z]+)<.*
```

You are asking for any amount of characters (`.*`), then at least a letter, then a `>`. So the greedy match has to be D, since `*` consumes everything before D.

In the second one, instead:

```
.*([A-Za-z]*)>([A-Za-z]+)<.*
```

You want any amount of characters, followed by any amount of letters, then the `>`. So the first * consumes everything up to the `>`, and the first capture group matches an empty string. I don't think that it "matches perfectly" at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using this regex:

```
<([A-Za-z]+)>([A-Za-z]+)<
```

OR

```
<([A-Za-z]*)>([A-Za-z]+)<
```

Both will match `LogicalID` and `SupplyChain` respectively.

**PS:** Your regex: `.*([A-Za-z]*)>([A-Za-z]+)<` is matching empty string as first match.

**Working Demo: http://ideone.com/VMsb6n**

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @kocko: Please elaborate why not. I wrote that OP's regex `.*([A-Za-z]*)>([A-Za-z]+)< is matching empty string as first match.`

Comment: The question is "Why `*` is greedier than `+` ?"

Comment: @kocko: The OP's "observation" (that `*` is greedier than `+`) seems to be based on a mistake; he thought his second regex matched "perfectly" while in fact it caused the capture group to match an empty string.

Comment: @kocko: That is what I tried to focus that OP's observation that `* is greedier than +` isn't right. (Added a working demo to showcase code example also).

Answer (score 1):

```
Why is * greedier than +?
```

It doesnot shows greedness.

The first regex `.*([A-Za-z]+)>([A-Za-z]+)<.*` can be represented as

[image]

Here Group1 should need to present one or more time for a match.

And the Second `.*([A-Za-z]*)>([A-Za-z]+)<.*` as

[image]

Here Group1 should need to present Zero or more time for a match.